# .NET Core Update migration is trying to re-create table again

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I was working on a .net core 3 project code first. In this step I added 2 columns into my tables. Then I made a migration addition to solution via this code (CLI).

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../MyApi.Api migrations add actorInfomart
```

My migration returned this:

```
public partial class actorInfomart : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
            name: "IsSeries",
            schema: "film",
            table: "Movie",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: false);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "ExtInfo",
            schema: "act",
            table: "Actor",
            maxLength: 100,
            nullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "IsSeries",
            schema: "film",
            table: "Movie");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "ExtInfo",
            schema: "act",
            table: "Actor");
    }
}
```

It seems correct. The problem is coming here. When I tried to update migration then I got this error :

```
There is already an object named 'Actor' in the database.
```

My migration is trying to create new table in my database. But in migration there is nothing for this. Here is my migration update CLI command.

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../MyApi.Api database update actorInfomart
```

In terminal (I am using Mac) writes

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20191231100058_Initial'.
Applying migration '20191231100058_Initial'.
```

How can I apply latest migration? I have 10 migrations between first and last. This is my first problem about migrations.

Comment: in your DB, you have a table __migrations_History, all applied migrations must be saved there. If is not, but is already applied (tables created or updated), when will try to apply it again, will throw in an exception

Comment: Either that or the table was already existing when you created your model and you didn't apply update for that first migration. On a side note: Migrations are always based on your snapshot (in the migrations folder), not on the actual db layout when you run `dotnet ef migrations add` command

Comment: I was truncate table so it also truncated migration table. I learnt that ef is looking migrations table for apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the problem in my db. Because of truncating '__EFMigrationsHistory' table in DB. The system's behavior is changing into initial migration as no migrations applied.

Answer (score 0):

I had my migration files and DataContextModelSnapshot.cs file and when I added new migration something happened and I saw same error and then I removed the last migrations files I added and  I removed related codes about that migration(u just can search for name of it. exmaple : "actorInfomart") then try to add migrations u wanted to add. and update database.
that worked for me and I planning solve like that anymore but I dont know the root reason...