# Why does my migrations create every table for the data model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've recently added a migration to my data model where I added a `bool` property to the `Member` model:

```
public class Member
{
    public bool IsLegacy { get; set; }
}
```

Having added the migration via `dotnet ef migrations add <name>`, the migration generated code to create every table.

As a result, when I push the migration to the database `dotnet ef database update`, I get an error saying

> table '...' already exists

The existing table could change from time to time.

I would expect the migration to simply add the column to the table so that the only could would probably be something like:

```
public partial class AddedLegacyFieldToMember : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
            name: "IsLegacy",
            table: "Member",
            type: "bit" // assuming sql type is what it needs.
        );
    }
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn("IsLegacy", "Members");
    }
}
```

So what I can't figure out is why the migration is trying to build every table all new as though no other migration exists.

The migration history table in the database does have the previous migration listed there though.

Have I done something wrong?

#### Note

I've tried using `.EnsureCreated()` to sidestep the issue, but clearly that's misguided as it didn't make any difference.

Also, building the migration logic into the Startup doesn't address the problem either.

Comment: try resetting all your migrations and re-initializing again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core Update migration is trying to re-create table again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561096/net-core-update-migration-is-trying-to-re-create-table-again)

Comment: @MohammadAghazade no because in that question, the migration that user indicated only shows the added columns whereas mine includes literally everything to build the database from scratch. It provides a clue in the answer involving truncating the MigrationHistory table, but that answer doesn't have any specifics I can use to address my issue.

Comment: Don't do `EnsureCreated` as it breaks the migrations system. Now, migration table (and database in general) is not used by add migration commands - they are based purely of the code content of the Migrations folder. Make sure you have all previous migrations classes there and valid {YourDbContext}ModelSnapshot.cs Looks like the command is thinking you are adding the initial migration, you need to find out why.

Comment: @IvanStoev is the snapshot supposed to include the new column I'm trying to add to my Members table? Because it's there

Comment: The snapshot is basically the model after last added migration (not sure why they need that). so its normal the column to be there after you added migration. Never delete manually these code files - use remove migration commands, which remove the last migration from the project and updates the snapshot. So, you need to remove the wrong migration using the remove migration command which should restore the original snapshot. Then try add migration again. Although the fact that it tries to create initial migration sounds like something there is corrupted, and I'm not sure how you can recover it.

Comment: Hi @psiodrake, you can run remove migration command and then add migration.

Comment: @Rena on a project at home last night, I changed from MSSQL to SQLite. I removed all previous migrations (deleted the Migrations folder) and added the new initial migration for SQLite. It generated the migration and snapshot and, with no database file in existence at this point, gave the same error - `table already exists`

Comment: Hi @psiodrake, also remember remove the existing database.